# andThen with lambda in Consumer interface

Tags: java, lambda, consumer

Can I chain andThen with lambdas?

I know I [can do it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449580/java-8-usage-of-consumers-andthen): `myList.forEach(myConsumer1.andThen(myConsumer2));`

but what if I want to supply a lambda `(e)->{ some actions }` instead of `myConsumer1` and another lambda  `(e)->{ some more actions }` instead of `myConsumer2`?

I tried and it does not work. But is it possible in general - maybe I don't know the right syntax.

P.S. My question (from practical point) is different from the one tagged ["maybe already answered"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418995/chaining-consumers-java-8) - it is just completely different, the linked post has no practically helpful information to my issue - and I don't know how to describe how crocodile is different from love.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just put everything in one lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this but you need to cast the lambda expression explicitly.

The lambda expression from your example `(e)->{ some actions }` is not necessarily the `Consumer`. It might be your own functional interface with the same signature as `void accept(T t);` from `Consumer`, but without `andThen` method. Compiler doesn't know that. So you need to help the compiler:

```
list.forEach(((Consumer<Integer>) e -> someAction).andThen(i -> someMoreAction));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it but it requires proper casting of the lambdas.

```
      int[] val = { 23
      };
      Consumer<Integer> con = ((Consumer<Integer>) (a) ->
      {
         for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
            val[0] += i;
         }
      }).andThen((b) -> System.out.println(val[0] * b));

      con.accept(10);
```